STM32 F446 Nucleo halts on Polymorphism
I'm wondering what the possible causes of an MCU halting on a polymorphic function call might be.
I have the following code.  I can call the member function directly on the non-pointer variable. However, once I cast the variable to a pointer of it's parent virtual class and try calling the member function through polymorphism, the mcu halts.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
// parent.h

#ifndef WAVES_2_DSP_ENGINE_PARENT_H
#define WAVES_2_DSP_ENGINE_PARENT_H

namespace waves2 {

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
    ~Parent() {}
    virtual void Init() = 0;
};

}

#endif

// child.h

#ifndef WAVES_2_DSP_ENGINE_CHILD_H
#define WAVES_2_DSP_ENGINE_CHILD_H

#include "waves2/dsp/engine/parent.h"

namespace waves2 {

class Child: public Parent
{
public:

    Child() { }
    ~Child() { }

    virtual void Init();

private:
    DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(Child);
};

}

#endif

// child.cc

#include "waves2/dsp/engine/child.h"

namespace waves2 {

void Child::Init() {
}

}

#endif

// main.cpp

Child child;

int main(void) {

  // this works fine
  child.Init();

  Parent* p = &child;
  // If I execute the following code,
  // the code which toggles the LED will not be reached
  p->Init();

  while(1) {
      // toggle led
      if((system_clock.milliseconds() / 1000) % 2 < 1) {
          GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5);
      } else {
          GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_5);
      }
  }
}


Your Child::Init() literally is an empty function, so how do you know the program halt at p->Init(), and not at the empty while(1){} loop?

I have code (not written in detail in the example) which turns on an LED following the polymorphic call.  If I run with the polymorphic code, the LED doesn't turn on.  If I run without the polymorphic code, the LED turns on.

Ok. Updated the code reference.

You either provide a minimum reproducible code or the complete code. Based on the C++ code you provided so far, it has nothing really to do with stm32 (other than blinking an LED), and is not reproducible. Your code not blinking might be because you never enable the GPIO clock (at least your code doesn't have anything like that)...

The complete code can be found here.
https://github.com/eclewlow/eurorack/tree/master/waves2

The pins are initialized correctly.  It blinks without the polymorphism.  That's how I know somethings wrong when it doesn't blink.  The build system/environment is from an open sourced eurorack module company.  I actually copy a lot of the code from the Plaits project (the polymorphism bit).

Are you perhaps compiling with RTTI (RunTime Type Information) disabled?

I did find this line in the build configuration
CPPFLAGS = -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
So I replaced it with the following and rebuilt, but still no success
CPPFLAGS = -fno-exceptions -frtti

I'm looking at the .map file for Plaits and the .map file for my project.  It seems like the lines that specify the vtable are completely missing in mine.  My project uses linker scripts for stm32f4xx and Plaits uses stm32f373x, so the linker scripts are different.  I'm wondering if there's something here.

Well, after editing the linker script, I was able to get the vtables to show up in the map file.  But it still won't execute the polymorphic function call.
